# How to monitor MySQL by Zabbix (in docker containers)?

Tags: mysql, docker, zabbix

I have:

1. Zabbix server (computer A)
2. Zabbix agent (computer B)
3. Mysql (computer B)

But all of this components work inside Docker containers. How could I monitor Mysql by Zabbix in this case?

I saw this page (https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/mysql). But i think, this won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use "[Template DB MySQL by Zabbix agent](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/mysql)":

- if the Zabbix Agent is not dockerized:

  - and the MySQL port is published/mapped:

    - just follow the [instructions](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/mysql_agent).
  - else:

    - map the port, and follow instructions.
- else:

  - check that mysql client is present in the docker image, add it if missing
  - link that container to the MySQL container, and follow instructions.